# What is the best way to manage authentication for a large number of servers in a datacenter?

Tags: linux, windows, security

I'm running a large number of servers (several hundreds) in a local datacenter. Currently most of them are Windows servers of various types, but more and more are Linux.

I would like to know what the best practice is for managing authentication on these servers for system administrators. I can deploy SSH keys to the Linux servers, and the Windows servers are domain members, but is it a better idea to use PAM to authenticate the Linux servers to the AD domain?

If I was running a completely homogeneous Linux environment, how would this answer change? Surely an AD domain wouldn't be reasonable if it were the *only* Windows machine?

Comment: You do whatever works for you. If your config management implementation allows you to easily manage local admin accounts on each server for your staff you don't need to implement single sign on and centralized authentication and if you do need/want that you can integrate with an AD domain, consider IPA or Kerberos and LDAP

Answer (score -1):

I would use a combination of AD and OTP (one time password - vaultssh works great)